# How to nest an existing if else with html code?

Tags: php

```
                                    <!--var1-->
                              <?php if ($box->mobile_number != Null) {echo '
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                                <p class="mb-0">Mobile Added</p></div>
                            </div>';
                                } else {echo'                                   
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
                                <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Mobile</a></p></div>
                            </div>';}?>
                            <!--var2-->
                                <?php if ($box->email_address != Null) {echo '
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Email Added</p></div>
                            </div>';
                                } else {echo'   
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Email</a></p></div>
                            </div>';}?>
                            <!--var3-->
                                <?php if ($box->address1 != Null) {echo '
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle "></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Address Added</p></div>
                            </div>';
                                } else {echo'   
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle "></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Address</a></p></div>
                            </div>';}?>
                            <!--var4-->
                                <?php if ($box->account_number != Null) {echo '
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-university"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle "></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Bank Added</p></div>
                            </div>';
                                } else {echo'   
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-university"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle "></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Bank</a></p></div>
                            </div>';}?>
```

Hi, I cant nest them inside IF (all_these_4_statements != Null) { echo '';} else { echo 'above_codes';}
Since both ' and " has been utilized.

all these 4 statements currently encapsulated in div tag

how to work on this?
thanks.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner lol, im not aware of it.
changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, so I am going to just answer this "generically".  If you want to clarify a bit further from here, I can add to my answer at a later point.  But, this is pretty much the structure you want for if/else statements:

```
<?php
if (some_condition) {
    // Do some coding/analyzing/variable setup, etc
    if (second_condition_with_data) {
      // A condition was met based on the data you setup after the first condition
    } else {
      // The secondary condition was not met and this is the default
    }    
} else {
   // Default circumstance if the original condition was not met
}
```

Comment: Also, just a tip, but when you are writing big blocks of HTML where there isn't much PHP inside of it, I recommend closing your PHP, doing the HTML, then opening back up the PHP.  It makes the code a bit more readable.  There are times when you have heavily mixed PHP with HTML and this may not be the way to go, but with your HTML blocks I would do this technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $box = $this->session->userdata("user");
                        if ($box->mobile_number && $box->email_address && $box->address1 && $box->account_number != NULL) {echo '';} else
                                        { echo'
                                    <div class="bg-light shadow-sm rounded p-4 mb-4">
                                    <h3 class="text-5 font-weight-400 d-flex align-items-center mb-3">Profile Completeness</h3>
                                        <div class="row profile-completeness">';}                               
                                    if ($box->mobile_number && $box->email_address && $box->address1 && $box->account_number != NULL) {echo '';} else
                                        {           
                                    if ($box->mobile_number != NULL) {echo '
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Mobile Added</p></div>
                                </div>';
                                    } else {echo'                                   
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
                                    <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Mobile</a></p></div>
                                        </div>';}}
                                    if ($box->mobile_number && $box->email_address && $box->address1 && $box->account_number != NULL) {echo '';} else
                                        {
                                    if ($box->email_address != NULL) {echo '
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                                        <p class="mb-0">Email Added</p></div>
                                </div>';
                                    } else {echo'   
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
                                        <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Email</a></p></div>
                                        </div>';}}
                                    if ($box->mobile_number && $box->email_address && $box->address1 && $box->account_number != NULL) {echo '';} else
                                        {
                                    if ($box->address1 != NULL) {echo '
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle "></i></span>
                                        <p class="mb-0">Address Added</p></div>
                                </div>';
                                    } else {echo'   
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span> <span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle "></i></span>
                                        <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Address</a></p></div>
                                        </div>';}}
                                    if ($box->mobile_number && $box->email_address && $box->address1 && $box->account_number != NULL) {echo '';} else
                                        {
                                    if ($box->account_number != NULL) {echo '
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-university"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-success mt-4 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-check-circle "></i></span>
                                        <p class="mb-0">Bank Added</p></div>
                                </div></div>
                                </div>';
                                    } else {echo'   
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                    <div class="border rounded p-3 text-center"> <span class="d-block text-10 text-light mt-2 mb-3"><i class="fas fa-university"></i></span><span class="text-5 d-block text-light mt-4 mb-3"><i class="far fa-circle "></i></span>
                                        <p class="mb-0"><a class="btn-link stretched-link" href="">Add Bank</a></p></div>
                                        </div></div>
                                </div>';}}?>
```

found solution.
hell of ugly code.
but it works.

duplicate the same parent condition for each child condition.